# Why are JQuery UI widgets noticeably bigger in Opera?

Tags: jquery-ui, opera

So I did a test of the actual size (width and height) of the jquery UI **[combobox button on the JQuery demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)** in Opera 12, IE9, and Firefox 15 to see if it was a zoom thing or something else.

Turns out the button sizes were actually different for the Opera browser and much bigger.

- Opera width/height: **30px** / **25px**;
- IE width/height: 24.2px / 19.37px;
- Firefox: 24.2px / 19.6px;

Why is that? I don't want huge JQuery controls when viewing in Opera. This is only for the JQuery controls too as the other controls on my page are the same size.

Comment: Are you setting your own sizes on these or just using defaults?  This is probably a difference between default style sheets in Opera vs others.  You might try using a normalize.css

Comment: @Mystere Man, Thanks for the tip, but I just tried this [normalize.css](http://code.google.com/p/normalize-css/) and it didn't work. Also tried another [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), but that one didn't work either.

Not sure what you mean about setting my own sizes as I'm just viewing the JQuery demo page with opera browser defaults.

Comment: Every browser has different defaults for it's css, which includes default size for buttons and other controls.  If a page does not explicitly set the size of a control, then whatever the default size is for that browser is used.  You can overcome this by setting the size explicitly in your css.  You have no control over the jqueryui page, so in order to test this you will have to create your own page.

Comment: Besides, I would think JQuery would explicitly define the styles with sizes so the look and feel and behavior is consistent across browsers.

Comment: No, jqueryui does not override control sizes, they leave that up to you.

Comment: jQuery UI uses `em` for sizes of everything.  This means you should set a global font size on the `html` so that all browsers are consistent.  Also, be careful when nesting em styled items as things can overlap and go wonky.

Comment: Thanks guys. Setting a default size at the html/body level to pt's or px's fixes it. Leaving it at the default em size setting (or setting it to any em size setting) is what is causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Nal and @Mystery Man's comments, if I set a default font size at the html and/or body level it to px's or pt's, it fixes the discrepancy. Setting it to any em setting is what was causing the issue since the default was 1em or something. The jquery demo pages just use the default jquery font size setting which is in em's and thus not an aboslute size.